# How can I retain value of some variable across requests in nginx?

Tags: ajax, nginx

When I hit a URL, a request to nginx server is made.
While loading the html view of the html page, there are some ajax requests.

When there was first request made through URL, I want to define a variable with some value in a location block of nginx conf. And in further ajax request, I want to use the value of that variable in some other location in nginx conf.

Is there a way out to retain the value of variable across requests?

Comment: AJAX request can have additional headers (and also cookies) that can be reused among number of subsequent requests